# Conditional Formatting in Google Sheets where Percantage Range is Involved

Tags: google-sheets, gs-conditional-formatting, google-sheets-query

I am trying to figure out how to do conditional formatting on a range of percentage in google sheets.

I want to fill the cell in question a certain colour depending on how much the percentage is of another cell.

I have learned out to do this for higher than 80% (red fill) and lower than 40% (green fill) but can't work out how to do it between 40% and 80% (in which case I'd want the fill to be Amber).

I have attached a screenshot of how I thought it should go but it's not working.

I'm sure i'm missing something really obvious but I can't work out what. Could someone please help?

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dlaVK.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Applies to range: `W83`

**Custom formula is**: `=and(W83>0.4*V83,W83<0.8*V83)`

40% and 80% exactly may not be covered, unless some `=`s are added somewhere, depending on unspecified requirement.

Comment: Thank you, that has worked! I knew it would be something simple so thank you!